# How to edit fieldname in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I exported a public dataset in Bigquery to my project. the first fieldname/column name reads 'f0_' instead of 'trip_duration'. I am using a free trial version. I am unable to query this because of the nature of the fieldname (f0_).

I had to query the fieldname twice before exporting it. this resulted in duplicating the fields. the first fieldname still remained 'f0_' while the second fieldname maintained the 'trip_duration'.

Comment: Can you use a column alias? `SELECT f0_ AS trip_duration, other_column1 FROM the_table`